# Dreamweaver CS5.5 live view doesn't work properly

Tags: dreamweaver

I have a simple question; hope you can help me.

I have coded a webpage with Dreamweaver CS5.5, and when I click Live view, it does not load properly (like CSS file is not loaded).[image: This is the screenshot]

Is there any way to fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have not defined your site and testing server in dreamweaver.

For testing server try something like:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\
```

Answer (score 2):

If your local files are on a network server, it is not likely to work (have same problem) and Adobe does not offer support in that case.  I moved my files to the local hard drive and it works fine there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Windows machine, create a mapped "network drive".  This will act like a local drive and will allow the live preview to function properly.

If you're on a mac, you may be able to create a "sym-Link" for a similar result.  But I haven't tried it.